# UltraESB throwing HTTP 503 or UnsupportedClassVersionError exception depeneding upon the JDK version

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, jetty

I am testing UltraESB 1.7.1 and have been following the [quickstart guide](http://docs.adroitlogic.org/display/esb/Quickstart+Guide) in order to do this. Part of the quickstart is to send a message through UltraESB via [these instructions](http://docs.adroitlogic.org/display/esb/Sending+a+Message+through+UltraESB). I have followed the instructions but keep getting a `Error 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` error returned from Jetty.

I had assumed that my issue was related to me running JDK 7, and not the recommended 6, so I swapped out my JDK, after which I get an exception when starting Jetty. The exception is:

```
roberth@ubuntu:~/Downloads/ultraesb-1.7.1/bin$ ./toolbox.sh 
Starting AdroitLogic UltraESB ToolBox ...
Using JAVA_HOME  : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
Using ULTRA_HOME: /home/roberth/Downloads/ultraesb-1.7.1
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: samples/services/hessian/HessianStockQuoteService : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Note: The entirety of the exception has not been posted - if you need more let me know.

Can anyone shed some light on what could be the issues?

System specs:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
- Oracle JDK 6u43/7u17
- UltraESB 1.7.1 Full

--EDIT--
I am able to reproduce the issue on Windows 7 using JDK 7u15. At this time it appears to be an issue with UltraESB itself as the OS has been eliminated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the reply from AdroitLogic here [https://getsatisfaction.com/adroitlogic/topics/unable_to_run_quickstart_error_503_service_unavailable_error_occurs]

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Thanks @Asankha, I will be dual posting in your forum, as well as here to ensure maximum visibility for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per the linked post by Asankha, the issue may be with multiple versions of the Java JDK installed on my machine.

As such I spun a new instance of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on VMWare and executed the following:

After install:

- `echo PATH` : `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games`
- `echo JAVA_HOME` :
- `which java` :

After installing oracle-java6-installer and oracle-java6-set-default from the webupd8team PPA as well as adding a test user (non-root):

- `echo PATH` : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin`
- `echo JAVA_HOME` : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle`
- `which java` :`/usr/bin/java` which is a symlink pointing to `/etc/alternatives/java`, which points to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle/jre/bin/java`

installing UltraESB 1.7.1 and running the demo results in the following:

- `JAVA_HOME` : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle`
- `ULTRA_HOME`: `/home/edi/ultraesb-1.7.1`

and a successful demo session!